# Three.js - Clip planes and homogeneous coordinate

Tags: three.js

I would like to better understand how an object transformed using the w homogeneous coordinate interacts with clip planes.

I've got a simple example of the effect at the plunkr below. The larger sphere has been "scaled" using the w component in its matrix, and the clipping plane no longer behaves the same with the transformed object as it does with the original object.

http://embed.plnkr.co/byuOjY4oWIx2QDrg5CV0/

I realize that this is not the correct way to scale an object in general, but I would be interested to get observations that might help me to apply a clipping plane to such an object.

Here's the relevant code:

```
  function drawSphere() {
  var leftClipPlane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0), 0);
  var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    shininess: 100,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
    combine: THREE.MixOperation,
    reflectivity: 0.3,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    clippingPlanes: [leftClipPlane]
  });
  sphereMaterial.color.setRGB(0.4, 0, 0.4);

  sphereObj = new THREE.Object3D();

  sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(SPHERE_SIZE, 16, 16),
    sphereMaterial);
  sphere.name = 'sphere';
  sphereObj.add(sphere);
  scene.add(sphereObj);

  var otherSphereObj = new THREE.Object3D();
  otherSphereObj.copy(sphereObj.clone(), true);
  otherSphereObj.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
  var transformMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

  transformMatrix.set(
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0.5
  );

  otherSphereObj.matrix.multiply(transformMatrix);
  scene.add(otherSphereObj);
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see YOUR code (not a similar example). You may have missed something, or have an incorrect order of operations, or something else non-obvious which we can't debug without your code.

Comment: For the sake of future readers, please include your code in your post. When (not if) your link dies, so does the context of your question.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, the plunkr code is my own code. I wrote it to try to isolate the issue with the clipping plane and w coordinate transforms. I'm still interested in any insights about that example.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and posting your code. I'm confused by your copying and cloning. Is there a reason you didn't just do `var otherSpehereObj = sphereObj.clone();`? Also, your scaling matrix is strange. You can either do `otherSphereObj.matrix.makeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);` or if you want to use a separate matrix do `var transformMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5); otherSphereObj.matrix.multiply(transformMatrix);`

Comment: Ah, the copy/clone stuff was left over from a cloning issue I was confused by, but I just forgot to clean it up. It should be just .clone(). Thanks for pointing that out. 

As for the scaling, yes, it's definitely a strange (wrong) way to scale an object, and I think it's corrupting the matrix for rendering, which I suspect is related to the clipping plane issue. I'm going to try applying a similar transformation vertex by vertex instead of using the object's matrix.

Comment: You shouldn't need to apply a geometry-based scaling. Scaling by an appropriate transformation matrix should be fine.